# How to connect the combo box with database fields using ruby on rails 3.0

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am having problem on how to connect the combo box with the fields on the database.. I google it but it seems that luck is not on my side.. I try several code, and I'm trying to think what is the problem with my code in _form.html.erb, here it is:

<%= f.select :classification_code, @tests.collect( {|p| [ p.description, p.classification_code ] }, {:include_blank =>'None'}) %>

and I'm having syntax error... how can I do it properly?

thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<%= f.select :classification_code, @tests.collect{|p| [ p.description, p.classification_code ] }, {:include_blank =>'None'} %>
```

Comment: Hello Arun, I tried your code and I got the error of NoMethodError.. I continue searching and lady luck shines on me and I solved my problem.. this is the solution I came up with.. 

<%= f.select(:classification_code, classifications_for_select, :prompt => 'Select') %> 

it's really simple..

anyway thank you for your concern.. :)

Comment: glad you fixed it. Thank you for posting the solution :-)